# Inverse image of every compact set is compact under a function

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a function such that $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for every compact set $K$ in $\mathbb R$. Then

1. $f$ is continuous
2. $\sup \limits_ {\mathbb R}f(x)<\infty$
3. $\inf \limits_ {\mathbb R}f(x)>-\infty$
4. $f$ is constant

If we consider the identity function $i:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, then it satisfies the hypothesis, but clearly 2. 3. and 4. are false by it. But I could not prove that 1. is true? Any help?

Comment: It is true. Consider a sequence and look at closures (remember that compact is the same as closed and bounded in the reals).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $$f(t) =\begin{cases} -t \hspace{0.5cm}\mbox{ if } t\leqslant -\frac{\pi}{2} \\ \tan t  \hspace{0.2cm}\mbox{ if } -\frac{\pi}{2} <t< \frac{\pi}{2}\\t \hspace{0.9cm}\mbox{ if } t\geqslant \frac{\pi}{2} \end{cases}$$ then preimage of every compact set is compact but $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: $f^{-1}([0,2])=f^{-1}([0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})\cup [\dfrac{\pi}{2},2])=[0,a)\cup[\dfrac{\pi}{2},2]$, where $a<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Thus it is not compact.

Comment: If $K$ is compact then $$f^{-1} (K) =\left(\left( -\infty , \frac{\pi}{2} \right] \cap  (-K)\right)\cup (\arctan K ) \cup \left( K\cap \left[\frac{\pi}{2} ,\infty\right)\right) $$ and the set is compact as sum of three compact sets.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$h:[0,1)\to[0,\to):x\mapsto\frac{x}{1-x}\;;$$

it’s easily verified that $h$ is a homeomorphism. Now let

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }x<0\\
h(x),&\text{if }0\le x<1\\
x-1,&\text{if }x\ge 1
\end{cases}$$

For $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ let $A_L=A\cap(\leftarrow,0]$ and $A_R=A\cap[0,\to)$; clearly $f^{-1}[A]=f^{-1}[A_L]\cup f^{-1}[A_R]$. Moreover, $f^{-1}[A_L]=A_L$, and $f^{-1}[A_R]=h^{-1}[A_R]\cup(A_R+1)$, so

$$f^{-1}[A]=A_L\cup h^{-1}[A_R]\cup(A_R+1)\;.\tag{1}$$

If $A$ is compact, each term on the righthand side of $(1)$ is compact, so $f^{-1}[A]$ is compact.